# typescript, error: "Debug Failure. False Expression" at forEachIdentifierInEntityName, typescript.js:24094:26

Tags: typescript

Got this strange error when upgraded Typescript version from 2.8.4 to 2.9.2:

```
ERROR in ./js/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
at forEachIdentifierInEntityName (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24094:2
at bindPropertyAssignment (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24044:17)
at bindStaticPropertyAssignment (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24029:13
at bindSpecialPropertyAssignment (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:24020:1
at bindWorker (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:23669:29)
at bind (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:23560:13)
at visitNode (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:14777:24)
at Object.forEachChild (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15021:24)
at bindEachChild (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:22352:16)
at bindChildrenWorker (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:22434:21)
at bindChildren (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:22322:17)
at bind (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:23571:21)
at C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:22328:94
at bindEach (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:22344:21)
at bindEachFunctionsFirst (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:22328:13)
at bindChildrenWorker (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:22426:21)
at bindChildren (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:22322:17)
at bindContainer (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:22270:17)
at bind (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:23574:21)
at bindSourceFile (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:21935:17)
at Object.bindSourceFile (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:21876:9)
at initializeTypeChecker (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:51156:20)
at Object.createTypeChecker (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:27045:9)
at Object.getTypeChecker (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:78949:79)
at synchronizeHostData (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:107271:21)
at Object.getEmitOutput (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:107671:13)
at Object.getEmitOutput (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\instances.js:187:41)
at getEmit (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:196:37)
at successLoader (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:34:11)
at Object.loader (C:\devel\autostream-web\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:21:12)
```

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "sourceMap": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "module": "es6",
  "target": "es6",
  "lib": [
    "es2017",
    "dom"
   ],   
  "allowJs": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

Question: how can I get suitable error message and what am I doing wrong? And, I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634229/error-at-typescript-compilation-with-webpack/50634358) question, but I'm not satisfied with the solution and explanation - I need to use at least the same target and do not roll it back to 'es3', which is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q="forEachIdentifierInEntityName"+"debug+failure"+typescript) finds [TypeScript bug 24111](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24111), which is fixed in TypeScript 3.0.1.  Try upgrading TypeScript.  If the problem is still there, follow the process to file a new TypeScript bug.

Comment: Thanks, will check with 3.0RC

Comment: This error does happen again on the version 12 of angular. any clues how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute "npm i typescript" in the same directory as your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no, it didn't work for me - I have the same error after this =(

Comment: please read posted question and answer if you have any idea about that question

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - i've make answer instead of comment =(

Comment: `npm i typescript` also solves the error `ERROR in Debug Failure. False expression: Host should not return a redirect source file from `getSourceFile`